# Graalvm not found within Java application

Tags: java, gradle, graalvm

I have an Apache Tomcat servlet in which I would like to run some *other* language - for this purpose, I would like to try to get **Graalvm** functionality working within **OpenJDK 17**.

I added the following dependency to my `build.gradle` file:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.sdk/graal-sdk
implementation group: 'org.graalvm.sdk', name: 'graal-sdk', version: '22.1.0'
```

The Gradle file parses and runs without issue, however when I try to access the Graalvm classes in my application (servlet), nothing is found!?

```java
import org.graalvm; // is not found
```

For a first test, I'd like to get something simple like the following to work:

```java
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.proxy.*;

...

try (Context context = Context.create()) {
    context.eval("js", "print('Hello JavaScript!');");
}
```

But this fails, as the required class (Context) is not found. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but what?

**Update**

Thanks to @Mohammed Fataka suggestion, the Gradle build now runs successfully. My IDE (eclipse) was still showing compile errors, however a "**Refresh Gradle Project**" resolved that issue. (Right-click on the project within the **Package Explorer**, then **Gradle** -> **Refresh Gradle Project**).

I now have a new problem in that the resultant servlet crashes with the following error message: `IllegalStateException: No language and polyglot implementation was found on the classpath. Make sure the truffle-api.jar is on the classpath.`

So I added the following dependency:

```
// https://mavenlibs.com/maven/dependency/com.oracle/truffle-api
implementation group: 'com.oracle', name: 'truffle-api', version: '0.8'
```

But this hasn't helped, the same error still occurs.

**Update 2**

I finally have it working, I needed to use a different dependency:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.truffle/truffle-api
implementation group: 'org.graalvm.truffle', name: 'truffle-api', version: '22.1.0'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.js/js
implementation group: 'org.graalvm.js', name: 'js', version: '22.1.0'
```

I hope this helps others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey there please try to see if you are required to add compiler for that, if yes then add to your plugins section in build.gradle

```
    id "org.graalvm.plugin.compiler" version "0.1.0-alpha2"
```

btw,i run the code you got i have no issue and i can access to them, try to see your repositories as well.
docs are [here](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/sdk/README.md)

Comment: thanks for the tip. My IDE (eclipse) still reports compile errors, however the Gradle build now runs through ... do you have any idea why the IDE can't see the JAR/classes?

Comment: you are welcome, i highly recommend you to use intelij idea, it is so far the best IDE for me, i don't know why eclipse couldn't do that since i am not using it.. Intelij does not have such this problem when i executed it.